# Can you get a breakdown by minute or hour for metrics in facebook GraphAPI?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get a breakdown of metrics such as page_storytellers_by_city for an hour or minute?
If it is possible could you please show me the syntax.
Ideally I would like to get a value for every minute of the day for this metric.
I currently have the query {pageID}/insights?access_token=[AccessToken]&date_format=U&method=get&metric=page_storytellers_by_city&period=day&pretty=0&since=1435302000&until=1442991600
which gives me the breakdown by days, but I want a breakdown by minute or hour.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the most granular value you can get for any metric in the GraphAPI is daily or higher. The metric page_storytellers_by_city has daily as its most granular value.